# How to see the directory of a file or folder in the file browser

Tags: files

I wanted to see the directory of a folder but the file browser only showes the name of the which when I write in the terminal it shows that the directory doesn't exist. How do I see the real directory in the file manager.

What I see in the file browser:

[image: What I see in the file browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to toggle the Location bar. There, you see and copy-paste the path.

---

[image: breadcrumbs]

--> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

[image: location bar]

Comment: Frustratingly, the ability to paste the path of a selected file or folder after hitting Ctrl+c is list since several Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @vanadium I'm sure what you say is important and valid, but it's hard to figure out what you meant... near "is list since"

Comment: I ment "lost". Formerly, if you pressed Ctrl+C, the clipboard would contain the bash-formatted full path of the file or folder, ready to paste in the terminal or elsewhere. Currently, to accommodate the "Desktop Icons" extension, a different entry is placed on the clipboard that you can't directly use elsewhere.

Comment: @vanadium, true. Content is something like `x-special/nautilus-clipboard copy ...`. The solution would be to use `Nemo` which still has the "normal" behavior and/or drag-n-drop the file/directory into the terminal which still works as expected.

Comment: @pLumo I am using a nautilus script for that. Python extensions adding an entry to the right-click menu can also be found. b.t.w., drag and drop to terminal also continues to work for nautilus

Answer (score 1):

if you right click on the file, and choose 'properties' you will find the parent directory of the file.  In the image below, the full directory path to my file is `/home/chick/SweetHome`

[image]